# Unity3D Door Open/Close Bug

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

I have a problem in my project. I created an animation to open the door and made it open whenever a button was pressed. Then I copied the animation and entered its value -1 to make the door close after 2 seconds, but if the character presses the door open button again while playing the closing animation, it plays that animation and this causes a bug in the game. I apologize for telling a little complicated. I am waiting for your answers. Here is my code ->

```
public Text text;
public Animator anim;

private void Start()
{
    text.enabled = false;
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
}

private void Update()
{
    if(text.enabled && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
    {
        anim.Play("DoorOpen");
    }
}
private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    text.enabled = false;
}
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    text.enabled = true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use the Animator Play() method and instead create parameters like a Trigger that.. well... triggers the animation.

Also, you don't say what's the error you're getting so it is hard to help you, but I guess the animation is restarting? You can set so the animations can't be transitioned to itself, so it won't restart if triggered again before finishing. Edit your AnimatorController asset, and click on the animation that shouldn't transition to itself, then uncheck where it says precisely that: "Can transition to itself". (Maybe you have to double click it, maybe you have to click on the transition, don't really remember right now, you'll figure it out :) ).